# TexStudio Then Miktex Installed in Wrong Order

Tags: miktex, installing, texstudio, paths

I installed TexStudio on my laptop without realizing I first needed Miktex (or texlive) I installed Miktex but the paths were not automatically recognized.

I uninstalled TexStudios and reinstalled it but this did not help.

I found one answer to a similar question which said I needed to delete the texstudio.ini file.  I can't find such a file!  What can I do now?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sophie

Comment: It is there in `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\texstudio`

Comment: I can't find a folder or file at that address. =(

Comment: I have it, but doesn't mention MiKTeX, except for the dvi viewer.

Comment: @Sophie: perhaps try the `Help> Check latex installation`  menu.

Comment: @Sophie The folder (AppData) is hidden by default. Either enable showing hidden files or go to your user folder and then type the address in the address bar.
Also, could you clarify what exactly the problem is?

Comment: If it does mention miktex, there should be no problem (even if it doesn't mention it, it should work as long the pathes don't point to some other texsystem). Did you try to compile an hello world document?